# Fast searching time for nearest neighbours

Tags: algorithms, nearest-neighbour

I am using KD trees to do nearest neighbour searching. My understanding is that it takes $O(n \log n)$ effort to create the tree where $n$ is the number of points and that it takes $O(m \log n)$ to do nearest neighbour searching for $m$ query points.

In my application, $m$ is in the tens of millions and so most of the time is spent searching through the tree. Is there a quicker way? Any other algorithms where the total searching time is smaller?

- the dimensionality $d$ is less than 4
- the size of $n$ is in the thousands
- all the query points are known ahead of time.

I use KD tree because it is simple but I am open to suggestions for other nearest neighbour algorithms where the total time (build time + searching time) is lower.